# Bootstrapping EC2 instances in an Amazon VPC using Chef & Knife in an environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, chef-infra, bootstrapping, knife

I got my Chef Server and Chef workstation configured on an AWS VM running Centos. I downloaded the chef-repo from GitHub as per the instructions.
I downloaded the keys from my Chef Server. I also had  keys from Amazon to use their EC2 API (AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY). I also created a key at Amazon for use with the instance (test.pem). All the keys are in ~chef-repo/.chef/ and in ~/.ssh/.
I am trying to bootstrap an existing ec2 instance in a specific environment and under a specific role.

I have used the following command:

```
knife bootstrap Server_IP --ssh-user root --sudo --identity-file ~/.ssh/test.pem --environment testing --node-name Centos_Node --run-list 'role[web_server]'
```

This command adds the node to the default environment.

Please help me to resolve the issue.

**NOTE: VPC does not have an internet gateway**.

I am following this link :

http://clarkdave.net/2013/05/creating-ec2-instances-in-an-amazon-vpc-using-chef-and-knife/

Comment: Can you access that via regular SSH?

Comment: The bootstrap works fine when I execute knife bootstrap IP but now I am stuck at a different problem.I want to configure this instance in a specific environment and roles.  knife bootstrap Ip --ssh-user root --sudo --identity-file ~/.ssh/Jyoti_Test_Key.pem --environment testing --node-name Centos_Node --run-list 'role[web_server]'. This command doesnot work

Comment: Question & details edited

Comment: when i execute knife bootstrap Ip it creates client how to add the node. I am so confused :(

Answer (score 1):

An EC2 instance in a VPC requires more infrastructure than a standalone EC2 instance (one that is not contained within a VPC). For example, you will need subnets, routes, route tables, security groups, a gateway, and potentially one or more NAT servers.

Answer (score 0):

All EC2 instance weather you choose a VPC or not comes with a VPC the default VPC. I don't think there is a choice of creating a EC2 instance without a VPC